# Why is the discharge longer

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, diodes

I made a very simple circuit like so:

[image]

Both R1 and R2 have the same value (100K).

The capacitor is a 100u.

When it’s charging, it takes about 20 sec to get from 0v to 5.05V (measured at the capacitor) but when I press the button to discharge it, it takes more then 35 sec to get from 5.5 to 0V...

I would expect the charge to take longer as it goes throught R1 and the diode (which I guess has a small resistance too) while it only have to go through R2 when discharging.

Why is the discharge longer ?

Comment: Normally you can expect differences in time depending on the threshold you choose near the target. Try to measure the time to 50% or 64% of the voltage instead 99 or 100% and see if it changes . There is some memory effect in e-caps so how long you spend at each level has some effect (<10%)

Comment: two things are happening faster than they should,  it should never get to 5.05V if the supplty is 5.00V. and the discharge to 0V is expected to take forever.  what is it that you are not telling us?

Comment: I agree with @Jasen. Try to measure the time to reach 2.5V (if supply is exactly 5V).

Comment: RC gives you time constant 100k*100u=10 seconds. It should take more than 3*10=30 seconds to go through 95% of charging/discharging. Either R1 is not 100k, or voltage is not constant.

Comment: I get up to 5.5V.. I guess my power source is not super precise (just like a 9V battery usually gives more then 9v when new ). I will give it another try while looking at something like 75% charge/discharge. I didn’t think about the fact that the last .7V would go through the resistor only, thanks for that info.

Answer (score 1):

There's something odd with your readings and others have addressed the effect of the diode. There are a couple of things that might be worth reviewing.

[image]

*Figure 1. Capacitor discharge voltage curve (top) and capacitor current (bottom). The negative current is because current is leaving the capacitor. Image source: [Electronics-Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_2.html).*

The concept of **time constant** is useful in RC or RL circuits. In the case of the RC discharge it is the time taken to discharge by 63% from an initial value and is assigned the Greek letter tau, τ, and τ = *RC*.

There are a few values worth remembering:

- The capacitor will discharge by 63% after 1τ.
- The capacitor will discharge by 95% after 3τ.
- The capacitor will discharge by 99% after 5τ.
- The capacitor will never completely discharge! (In reality it will get close enough to zero that you won't be able to measure it anymore.)

For your tests and given that you have a diode in there I would suggest that you do the following:

- Measure the battery voltage and calculate 63% of that.
- Connect your test circuit and time how long it takes to charge to 63%.
- Calculate your τ and see if it matches. (Don't forget to allow for capacitor tolerance.)
- Let it charge fully - 10τ at least.
- Calculate 37% of the fully charged voltage and time how long it takes to discharge to that value.

The two experiments should give fairly close times but the 0.7 V drop of the diode will affect the charge time. If you want you can modify the charge measurement to be 63% of V<sub>bat</sub> - 0.7 and see if that improves the comparison.

Answer (score -1):

The diode is bypassing the resistor R2 causing the cap to charge via R1 only. When you press the button the diode is bypassed by the switch dumping the cap to ground via R2 while R1 is dumped directly to ground. This neglects the Vf of the diode.

Comment: Ehm, I don't think you've explained why discharge is 75% longer than charge - and that's the question.